# Manipulating string in PHP to make array of IDs and variables

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I have a string that looks like so:

```
orders = "{1:2, 3:4, 23:45, 12:56}"
```

**These orders couplets can vary in length**

The first number on the left of colon is the ID and the second number is the quantity,
i.e, 12:56 = ID: 12 Quantity: 56.

It's in this string format so I can easily store it in a database as one big chunk.

I want to get the string in the format:

```
Array (
    ID => Quantity,
    ID => Quantity
)
```

Like;

```
Array (
   1 => 2,
   3 => 4
)
```

So far, I have removed all the brackets with statement:

```
$string = substr(orders, 1, (strlen($intel['order']) - 2));
```

Then I have used the statement:

```
$chunks = explode(",", $string);
```

to give me : 
`Array (
   [0] => 1:2
   [1] => 3:4
)`

Is there a simpler way to format this array?
My second port of call was to use ANOTHER 
`$chunks2 = explode(":", $chunks);`
But I'm having trouble setting the index as the ID number..

Thanks guys.

---

-> Ultimatly, I will use a for loop to run multiple UPDATE SQL statements to change the 'stock' of an item to ('stock' - 'quantity') WHERE id = this id.

Answer (score 2):

```
$orders = "{1:2, 3:4, 23:45, 12:56}";
//Clean up 
$orders = substr(trim($orders),1,-1);
//Separate
$orders=explode(',',$orders);
$final=array();
//Loop
foreach ($orders as $order) {
  //Explode
  $order=explode(':',trim($order));
  //Sanitize
  if (sizeof($order)!=2) die("Bad data: Error 1");
  if (!is_numeric($order[0]))  die("Bad data: Error 2: '".$order[0]."'");
  else $order[0]+=0;
  if (!is_numeric($order[1]))  die("Bad data: Error 3: '".$order[1]."'");
  else $order[1]+=0;
  //Tabulate
  if (!isset($final[$order[0]])) $final[$order[0]]=$order[1];
  else $final[$order[0]]+=$order[1];
}

print_r($final);
```

Answer (score 1):

Really you should probably be looking at storing these in separate rows with related ID and Qty, but if you must store things in one lump like this I would use JSON / serialize() or something else easily usable.  However this should work:

```
preg_match_all('/(\d+):(\d+)/', $orders, $matches);
$result = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
```

Comment: This would fail on bad input, such as `{ ... abc12:34def, ...}`. Ofcourse if the input needs no sanitizing, this will be the fastest way ... +1.

Answer (score 0):

**Inbuilt Serialize/Unserialize Functions**

If you are not too strict on the format of the string, I suggest you to have a look at the '[serialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)' and '[unserialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)' functions.

serialize($array) will convert an array into a string, like this:

```
a:size:{key definition;value definition;(repeated per element)}
```

So,

```
Array ( 1 => 2, 3 => 4) will become "a:2{i:1;i:2;i:3;i:4}"
```

[where i means integer and a means array]

And unserialize($string) will convert back the string into an array.